# Maximum join of relations

Tags: databases

I have a question as follows

> Consider the relations $r1(P, Q, R)$ and $r2(R, S, T)$ with primary keys $P$ and $R$ respectively. The relation $r1$ contains $2000$ tuples and $r2$ contains $2500$ tuples. The maximum size of the join $r1⋈ r2$ is :

My attempt - Suppose all value of $R$ in $r1$ are same.  Then it should be $4499$.

But it's given $2000$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why downvote out of nowhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r1⋈ r2$ is the natural join of $r1$ and $r2$/ That is inner join on the common attribute $R$, where $R$ is the primary key of $r2$. It is Cartesian product of $r1$ and $r2$ followed by selection.

For each element $(a,b)\in r1⋈ r2$, where $a=(p,q,r)$ and $b=(r', s,t)$, we must have $r=r'$. That is, $b=(r,s,t)$. Since $R$ is the primary key for $r2$, for any $a\in r1$, there is at most one $b$ that can "join" $a$. So we will have at most 2000 tuples.

By the way, I could not see why "Suppose all value of R in r1 are same. Then it should be 4499". It is not even an option in [the original problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-it-2006-question-14/).

Comment: Thanks, don't know why it happens. I don't know what the hell I was thinking then...

Comment: And why downvotes to questions?

Comment: You should ask that why as a comment to your question. I did not downvote.